# Where does recordPlot() store par() and layout() for first plot?

Tags: r

In the following recorded plot, I cannot find the instruction that constructs the layout and sets the par() settings before the first plot.new call()

```
library( PerformanceAnalytics )
data( managers )

# write the plot to the open device
suppressWarnings(charts.RollingRegression(managers[, 1:6], managers[, 8, drop=FALSE], Rf = .04/12, colorset = rich6equal, legend.loc="topleft"))

# record = investigate the primitive calls.  notice no par() nor layout() before the first call to plot.new()
recorded = recordPlot()
lapply(recorded[[1]], "[[", 1 )

# as a result, the following creates one plot per page, not 3 on the same page:
lapply( recorded[[ 1 ]] , function( x ) { do.call( x[[ 1 ]] , as.list( x[[ 2 ]] ) ) } )
```

Perhaps this is encoded in `recorded[[ 2 ]]` which looks like some kind of encoded raw data?  If so, how could I grab the insructions prior to the first plot.new() from the raw data?

**Edit**
Warning: dirty hack.
If you want to encode the initial state in the instruction list, here's how:

```
tryCatch( dev.off() , error = function( e ) {} )
plot.new()
par( new = TRUE )
originalLayoutFunction = graphics:::layout
graphicsEnvironment = as.environment( "package:graphics" )
newLayoutFunction = function( ... )
{
    originalLayoutFunction( ... )
    par( mfg = c( 1 , 1 ) )
}

unlockBinding( "layout" , env = graphicsEnvironment )
assign( "layout" , newLayoutFunction , envir = graphicsEnvironment )
lockBinding( "layout" , env = graphicsEnvironment )

tryCatch( YOUR_PLOT_CALL_HERE , finally = 
                                { 
                                    unlockBinding( "layout" , env = graphicsEnvironment )
                                    assign( "layout" , originalLayoutFunction , env = graphicsEnvironment )
                                    lockBinding( "layout" , env = graphicsEnvironment )                                    
                                } )
recordedPlot = recordPlot()
dev.off()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably right about what's in `recorded[[2]]`.  My suspicion is that it contains the `SEXP` which "nicely hides the internals" referenced in this comment from the R sources:

```
/****************************************************************
 * GEcreateSnapshot
 ****************************************************************
 */

/* Create a recording of the current display,
 * including enough information from each registered
 * graphics system to be able to recreate the display
 * The structure created is an SEXP which nicely hides the
 * internals, because noone should be looking in there anyway
 * The product of this call can be stored, but should only
 * be used in a call to GEplaySnapshot.
 */
```

A bit further down in the same file ([`$SRC_HOME/src/main/engine.c`](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#bor5KmW_n7E/pub/freeware/SOURCES/R-2.4.1.tar.gz%7C53H-z5VQ3LU/R-2.4.1/src/main/engine.c)) is another possibly illuminating passage.

Like the comment above (and like the `recordPlot` help file), it too comes with a strongish admonition not to try mucking around with the objects stored by `recordPlot()`. "Here be dragons", they all say, and it looks like you are starting to meet them that were warned about ;)

```
/****************************************************************
 * GEplaySnapshot
 ****************************************************************
 */

/* Recreate a saved display using the information in a structure
 * created by GEcreateSnapshot.
 *
 * The graphics engine assumes that it is getting a snapshot
 * that was created in THE CURRENT R SESSION
 * (Thus, it can assume that registered graphics systems are
 *  in the same order as they were when the snapshot was
 *  created -- in patricular, state information will be sent
 *  to the appropriate graphics system.)
 * [With only two systems and base registered on each device at
 * creation, that has to be true: and grid does not save any state.]
 *
 *  It also assumes that the system that created the snapshot is
 *  still loaded (e.g. the grid namespace has not been unloaded).
 *
 * It is possible to save a snapshot to an R variable
 * (and therefore save and reload it between sessions and
 *  even possibly into a different R version),
 * BUT this is strongly discouraged
 * (in the documentation for recordPlot() and replayPlot()
 *  and in the documentation for the Rgui interface on Windows)
 */
```

Comment: I was afraid of this!  Its too bad because the lapply works quite nicely.  The only thing missing is the initial state.  Thanks, Josh!

Comment: I think there's a way to fool R to include the initial layout/par in the instruction list.  The problem is that layout() forces the next plot to plot on a new page.  So before saving the plot, you could: plot.new(); par( new = TRUE ); and then (hand waving) intercept the layout call and call par(mfg=c(1,1)) then graphics:::layout(...)  thoughts?